# Can I use "Before Since" in my sentence?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, prepositional-phrases

I want to say I love to watch scientific documentaries. And I started to watch them before I started kindergarten.

Is it right to say:

> "I love to watch scientific documentaries **before since** I started kindergarten"

?

Comment: What do you mean by it though?

Comment: I want to say I love to watch scientific documentaries. And I started to watch them before I started kindergarten.

Answer (score 8):

Reverse the order, "since before I started kindergarten" D

Comment: And it should be something like "I have loved watching ..."